# How can I create an image that I want to alter based on a percentage (svg or pure css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

For the site I'm currently working on it has a zombie theme and people can submit things into a pot and a winner wins the pot.

For the loading bar kind of thing I wanted to have a zombie, I was thinking the one from the left of this picture: [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-olXlVfHcfo0/VEWS4yHll6I/AAAAAAABEw8/YQdm7R2SpP8/s1600/Zombie%2BConrad%2Band%2BRhett.jpg)

I wanted to kind of fill it up with a fluid (kind of resembling blood) as people put stuff in, then when it fills to 100% the pot will be drawn.

I was curious if I have to turn this image into an SVG or if I can recreate this image with CSS I wanted to have a liquid effect like wavy on top I was wondering what would be the best method for approaching this.

If you need anymore information just ask. Thanks.

I was thinking something like this: http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/xrwja

My main question is: Can I convert this zombie image directly to CSS somehow or can I achieve this effect by turning it into a SVG and doing it some how? (I have no experience with using SVG)

```
Code pen link needs code apparently even though its not mine
```

Comment: maybe css background gradients? if the image is a cutout, you can make the background black and have a red gradient slowly move up. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: check this out as an example: https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/

Comment: This is probably what you want: http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/xrwja

Comment: @Derek Thanks that is what I wanted but I was curious if I could turn the zombie picture into a SVG or if I can convert that image into pure CSS some how

Comment: @Datsik search Google for "convert PNG to SVG". There appear to be some online tools available. I've done it using GIMP before with just a few steps but do not remember exactly, something about "Convert to Path". I don't see why you want it as CSS though. Use a PNG and make the inner parts transparent.

Comment: what came to mind was masking https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ but i'm not sure if that's the best and i couldn't figure it out on my own. I'm really curious to know how this turns out!

Comment: @Derek When you say make the inner parts transparent I'm guessing you mean the inside of the zombies body, but how would I stop the liquid from showing outside of the body?

Comment: The outside of the image would be white or whatever color the background of your website is. So the actual wave pattern would be a large rectangle or square, but since there would be a solid white image with the zombies being transparent, then the user would only see the zombies filling with liquid. There are multiple ways to do it, but I'd recommend the method of using a PNG overlay. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/djnBD/

Comment: @Derek it's difficult because my background is like a wallpaper I got the path converted to an svg just fine so i have the outline now I just need to figure out how to animate the path